# Visual Studio 2008 DataGrid column width changing

Tags: datagrid, visual-studio-2008, windows-forms-designer

I have a project for hand terminal and It use visual studio 2008.
I want to change column width but I tried  many things and It didn't work.
Here is my example code for creating column

```
           col = table.Columns.Add();
            col.ColumnName = "Column1";
            col.DataType = typeof(string);
            col.Caption = "Column1";
```

How can I do that. I'm stuck

I tried some solutains

```
DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView.Columns[0];
column.Width = 60;
```

```
gridName.Columns[0].FillWeight = 200;
gridName.Columns[1].FillWeight = 50;
```

when I write grid name It I can't do `gridName.Column`. This isn't work